# Fetching multiple entries of same id in django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-views

I am trying to make a query and retrieve all the data listed under that particular user with the help of the primary key. I am getting the data but it consists of only one data but I should get three.

Here is the views:

```
def eachlead(request, pk):
    # print(pk)
    lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
    leadinfo = LeadDetail.objects.filter(id=pk)
    print(list(leadinfo))
    return render(request, "onelead.html", {'lead': lead, 'leadinfo': leadinfo})
```

Here is models:

```
class LeadDetail(models.Model):
    Lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    files = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='media')
    tasks = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Lead.first_name 

class Lead(models.Model):
    lead_status = (
        ('Potential', 'Potential'),
        ('Prospect', 'Prospect'),
        ('Negotiation', 'Negotiation'),
        ('Converted', 'Converted'),
        ('Failed', 'Failed')
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True)
    agent = models.ForeignKey('Agent', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=lead_status, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='media')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

The response I am getting is `[<LeadDetail: Test1111>]` or `[{'id': 1, 'Lead_id': 1, 'files': 'media/dummy.pdf', 'tasks': 'Meeting at 19:00 Friday'}]` but there are 3 tasks under this ID:

[image]

Comment: Well, you should query on foreign key instead of pk.Try  querying `leadinfo = LeadDetail.objects.filter(lead_id=pk)` .

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to get `LeadDetail` from the query, but there is only **one** value with the pk. Instead of filtering directly via `id`, you have to filter with the `lead`.

```
def eachlead(request, pk):
    # print(pk)
    lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
    leadinfo = LeadDetail.objects.filter(Lead=lead)
```

Or, you can also do:

```
def eachlead(request, pk):
    # print(pk)
    lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
    leadinfo = LeadDetail.objects.filter(Lead__id=pk)
```

[Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/) to django queryset.

Answer (score 0):

```
lead.leaddetail_set.all()
```

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) more info